# How to disable log statements in QuickBlox?

Tags: quickblox

Quickblox often logs stuff like:

```
Performing async request: 
RestRequest:
------
POST http://api.quickblox.com/session.xml
headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.5.2";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
```

But sometimes I want to disable QB logs to see the logs produced by my code more clearly. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[QBSettings setLogLevel:QBLogLevelNothing];
```

Comment: for android QBSettings.getInstance().setLogLevel(LogLevel.NOTHING);